# Getting error while using windRose() function from openair package in R language

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a wind rose diagram using `openair` package function `windRose()` in R language. I have sample data for wind directions and wind speeds in a **.csv file**. The csv file data is also pasted to the post.

In R I have loaded the `openair` package and read the data from csv file to a `dataframe` data. when I am calling the `windRose()` function as shown below I am getting an error.

```
windRose(data,wd="dir",ws="spd")


Error in if (mean.wd < 0) mean.wd <- mean.wd + 360 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**
```

can some one please help me in finding the issue.

sample csv file contents

```
dir,spd
343,4.4
293,4.3
157,14.1
166,9.4
117,14.4
5,13.5
335,5.3
87,14.3
130,14.7
301,12.6
330,13.1
265,9.1
70,13.4
257,11.0
174,4.2
97,12.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Renaming your columns, to **ws** and **wd** corrects the problem:

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'wd,ws    ## I use wd and ws
343,4.4
293,4.3
157,14.1
166,9.4
117,14.4
5,13.5
335,5.3
87,14.3
130,14.7
301,12.6
330,13.1
265,9.1
70,13.4
257,11.0
174,4.2
97,12.2',header=T,sep = ',')

windRose(dat)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much. I just did what you suggested and the windrose got plotted very nicely.